# Creating a MVC 3 Site theme design

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, themes

I have a MVC 3 web application for which I would like to implement a theme/templating framework (similar to Wordpress or Joomla where you can enable or disable different themes for a site) and would like to find out what is the best way to accomplish this.

My design constraints are this. I buy HTML templates from places like Themeforest or Template Monster and want to make a number of these templates available for use in my web app. The templates you typically buy online all have very different CSS layout frameworks, so it's not possible to just drop a new CSS in your /Content/Themes/ folder and then your views work with this because you also have to make changes to the HTML in the Views. So for every new theme in /Content/Themes I also need a new set of /Views/ folders where the HTML is updated to use the proper CSS classes for that theme.

I know in an ideal world I should just have all the CSS compatible with my html views (ie theme switching is purely based on loading a new CSS), but in this case that is just not possible.

So I'm wondering if there is way to tell MVC where the current default Views folder is? A possible project structure I'm thinking of is something like this:

> /Themes/Theme1/Views/(all cshtml view pages for this theme goes here)
>   /Themes/Theme2/Views/(etc)

I know that I can force the views like this

```
return View("~/Themes/Theme1/Views/Controller/Index.cshtml")
```

which can be extended to dynamically determine the theme folder with something like this

```
return View(currentThemeFolder + "/Views/Controller/Index.cshtml")
```

but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? Is there someway perhaps in the global.asax to set the default "Views" folder so that the above is not necessary? There must be an entry point to the views because how do you then specify which _viewstart.cshtml file is called? And if I do go for the above design of forcing/"semi-hard-coding" the views what are the down sides to it?

I also want to say that I have not looked much at Areas in MVC 3 and I don't think that would work here, because my understanding is that it would affect your routing, and would also duplicate your model and controllers folders which I don't want. I have on central Model and Controllers folders, but just need multiple Views folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend VirtualPathProviderViewEngine to create your own themeable view engine. Here is how:  http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Creating_a_Custom_View_Engine_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx